# In sensu, how to configure log level?

Tags: monitoring, logging, sensu

I've just installed sensu (with the debian "omnibus" package) and I couldn't find any way to change the log level.

Is there any way to do it in both client and server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borrowed from sensu FAQ: http://sensuapp.org/docs/0.12/faq#how-do-i-increase-log-verbosity

> You can adjust the process log level by setting LOG_LEVEL in
>   /etc/default/sensu to either debug, info, warn or error. You will need
>   to restart the Sensu process(s) after making the adjustment.

This will work for both server and client. Don't forget to restart the sensu services you want to debug

```
# echo "LOG_LEVEL=debug" >> /etc/default/sensu
# service sensu-server restart
# service sensu-api restart
# service sensu-client restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my environment (Ubuntu) I had to modify the log level setting in /opt/sensu/bin/sensu-service:

```
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```